# Force 2 elements on the same line, always

Tags: css

I have a table that has the following contents:

[image]

Created like this:

```
<div class="currency">1,280.00</div>

div.currency {
    text-align: right;
    width: 100%;
}

div.currency:before {
    content: "$";
    float: left;
}
```

Problem is that when the table cell is not wide enough it will overflow the dollar symbol to the next line. What is not clear in my example is that the $ sign will align fully left and the decimal value right (accounting style in Excel).

Is there a way to force them on the same line always and have it resize the table cell, like it does with long strings?

Comment: It seems fine if you don't float the pseudo element? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GWbmWr if you need to create space between the pseudo element and the #, use a margin there.

Comment: You can use bootstrap. Ex: You can wrap your table with 'table-responsibe' class. Note this is just a suggestion.

Comment: @MichaelCoker sorry that wasn't completely clear in my example, but we have it "accounting" style, so the currency is left aligned, the actual value right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use flexbox on that and by default, a flex `row` is set to `nowrap` so it won't wrap. Then use `justify-content: space-between` to separate the elements instead of using `text-align` and `float`

```css
div.currency {
  width: 50px;
  background: #ccc;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

div.currency:before {
  content: "$";
}
```

```html
<div class="currency">1,280.00</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In that you can use **nowrap** in table cell.

```
<table  >
    <td style="width: 99%"></td>
    <td nowrap> <div class="currency">1,280.00</div></td>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
div.currency {
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
}

div.currency:before {
    content: "$";
    float: left;
}
```

Live link: https://jsfiddle.net/3a0nwr5t/1/